# how do i save return values from a .each call into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function i call:

```
CreateNode(e,control);// which will return an ID.  
                      // e i leave alone, but i was thinking that i 
                      // could pass the object into the function this way optionally.


function CreateNode(e, control){
if(!control) control = this;
// for rest of function, calls to the object are $(control) instead of $(this).
//...
}
```

I then have a selector i want to iterate over:

```
$(control_group).each(createNode);
```

Is there a way to build a list of IDS from this, such as:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push($(control_group).each(createNode));
```

I am doing a recurive control builder which makes controls in controls, and so i want to return identifiers into a child attribute.  That is what i was going to do with *arr*.

My one idea was doing something simple like:

```
var arr = [];
$(control_group).each(function(e){
    arr.push(createNode(e,$(this));
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what `.map()` does:

```
var arr = $(control_group).map(createNode).get();
```

`.map()` returns a jQuery object; if you want an ordinary array, you need to `.get()` it.

Comment: My case seems to returning an array of size one, the last execution of createNode from the .map().   Is there something else going on i am unaware of/

Comment: What is `$(control_group)`?  Note that `map()` may not pass the parameters you want.